# Face-tracking libraries for Java or Python

Tags: java, python, face-detection

I'm looking for a way to identify faces (not specific people, just where the faces are) and track them as they move across a room.

We're trying to measure walking speed for people, and I assumed this would be the easiest way of identifying a person as a person. We'll have a reasonably fast camera for the project, so I can probably use some logic for seeing if "face1 in frame00 == face1 in frame01".

Ideally such a software would return a list of faces (as in x,y locations) and their sizes.

Comment: Be careful with your choice of words. Try face detection as a search term because identify or recognize are mostly used for finding specific faces

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checkout [OpenCV Python Interface](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/PythonInterface)

Answer (score 2):

"faint" (The Face Annotation Interface) might be what you're looking for.

http://faint.sourceforge.net/

http://technoroy.blogspot.com/2008/06/faint-search-for-faces.html

I never used it myself. However, I played with the application which bundles with faint.

Answer (score 2):

There was an [article about this](http://www.linux-magazin.de/heft_abo/ausgaben/2008/02/ins_gesicht_geblickt) in the German "Linux Magazin".

They used the [Open Computer Vision Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) which offers a whole bunch of algorithms to process images in various ways.

Answer (score 0):

[CodeProject has a whole raft of articles in various languages.](http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=face+recognition)